# react-stripe-elements styling Card Element

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm using the module react-stripe-elements and I want to style the CardElement to create something like the attached. Can someone please help?[image]

https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react

```
<CardElement
  options={{
    style: {
      base: {
        fontSize: '16px',
        color: '#424770',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#aab7c4',
        },
      },
      invalid: {
        color: '#9e2146',
      },
    },
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)